# Experience (XP) not working for all users JSON Discord.PY

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to give points for messages typed in a room that has around 50-60 people that type in it. It will add the user to the JSON file the first time, but it won't add any more points for the messages they type. I tested it again and only one user was getting points for the messages they typed and the rest remained the same. Here is the code:

```
 @client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.lower().startswith('!points'):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "You have {} points!".format(get_points(message.author.id)))

    user_add_points(message.author.id,1)

def user_add_points(user_id: int, points: int):
    if os.path.isfile("users.json"):
        try: 
            with open('users.json', 'r') as fp:
                users = json.load(fp)
            users[user_id]['points'] += points
            with open('users.json', 'w') as fp:
                json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        except KeyError:
            with open('users.json', 'r') as fp:
                users = json.load(fp)
            users[user_id] = {}
            users[user_id]['points'] = points
            with open('users.json', 'w') as fp:
                json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent = 4)
    else:
        users = {user_id:{}}
        users[user_id]['points'] = points
        with open('users.json', 'w') as fp:
            json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def get_points(user_id: int):
    if os.path.isfile('users.json'):
        with open('users.json', 'r') as fp:
            users = json.load(fp)
        return users[user_id]['points']
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages?

Comment: No error messages in the code or when I run it :(. It's so odd. Could it be an issue with permissions of the actual server? I tested it in my test server and it was adding up my XP, but I added the bot to the other server that it doesn't have admin perms on, and it adds members, but only adds the user id and "1". For one user id though, it keeps counting the lines they are , for the others, it remains at "1".

Comment: Okay, so I tried it on another server with admin privs, I noticed that it will count the first person who typed "points" or lines sent, but when others are added, they stay the same and nothing is added to their "points" in the JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should only need to read the file once, and then just save our modifications to the file when we need to. I didn't notice any logical errors that would lead to the behavior described, so it may be a permissions issue regarding what messages your bot is allowed to see.  To facilitate debugging, I've simplified your code and added some prints to track what's going on.  I also added a guard in `on_message` to stop the bot from responding to itself.

```
import json
import discord

client = discord.Client()

try:
    with open("users.json") as fp:
        users = json.load(fp)
except Exception:
    users = {}

def save_users():
    with open("users.json", "w+") as fp:
        json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def add_points(user: discord.User, points: int):
    id = user.id
    if id not in users:
        users[id] = {}
    users[id]["points"] = users[id].get("points", 0) + points
    print("{} now has {} points".format(user.name, users[id]["points"]))
    save_users()

def get_points(user: discord.User):
    id = user.id
    if id in users:
        return users[id].get("points", 0)
    return 0

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    print("{} sent a message".format(message.author.name))
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!points"):
        msg = "You have {} points!".format(get_points(message.author))
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
    add_points(message.author, 1)

client.run("token")
```

Comment: This works flawlessly. Thank you again Patrick! I'm sure you are getting sick of all of my questions haha.