# show user level system Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

i'm working on add level system

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os
import asyncio
import time
import random
from discord import Game
import math, time

Client = discord.client
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
Clientdiscord = discord.Client()

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Hema\Desktop\Level')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print('lvl ready')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
    users = json.load(f)

    #code
    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
    await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)



with open('users.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(users, f)


if message.content == 'system lvl':
    await client.send_message(message.channel, '{} level up {}'.format(message.author.mention, lvl_end))
    users[message.author.id]['level'] = lvl_end

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
    users = json.load(f)

#code

await update_data(users, member)

with open('users.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
if not user.id in users:
    users[user.id] = {}
    users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
    users[user.id]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
users[user.id]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
experience = users[user.id]['experience']
lvl_start = users[user.id]['level']
lvl_end = int(users[message.author.id]["experience"] ** (1/4))

if lvl_start < lvl_end:
    await client.send_message(channel, '{} level up {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
    users[user.id]['level'] = lvl_end


client.run("Token")
```

work perfectly ^)

but problem showing when i want to know user level, by typing "system lvl"
showing this error

```
=========== RESTART: C:\Users\Darzy\Desktop\Level\Bot_lvl.py ===========

lvl ready
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Darzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Darzy\Desktop\Level\Bot_lvl.py", line 31, in on_message
await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)
File "C:\Users\Darzy\Desktop\Level\Bot_lvl.py", line 67, in level_up
lvl_end = int(users[message.author.id]["experience"] ** (1/4))
NameError: name 'message' is not defined.
```

i just wounder if it possible to fix that problem, i tried many methods, not worked:
beside that, just modified author for user and still the same problem.
i believe in stackoverflow. developers community ^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered From another Thread.

[Experience (XP) not working for all users JSON Discord.PY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922926/experience-xp-not-working-for-all-users-json-discord-py?rq=1)

```
import json
import discord

client = discord.Client()

try:
with open("users.json") as fp:
    users = json.load(fp)
except Exception:
users = {}

def save_users():
with open("users.json", "w+") as fp:
    json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def add_points(user: discord.User, points: int):
id = user.id
if id not in users:
    users[id] = {}
users[id]["level"] = users[id].get("level", 0) + points
#  print("{} now has {} level".format(user.name, users[id]["level"]))
save_users()

def get_points(user: discord.User):
id = user.id
if id in users:
    return users[id].get("level", 0)
return 0

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author == client.user:
    return
# print("{} sent a message".format(message.author.name))
# if message.content.lower().startswith("!points"):
#     msg = "You have {} points!".format(get_points(message.author))
#     await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
add_points(message.author, 0.01)

if message.content == '!Lvl':
    msg = "Your Lvl {}!".format(get_points(message.author))
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)        


client.run("token")
```

`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from your code, channel is not defined within that function. Now, I am not familiar with the Python discord library, but it seems like you can use `message.channel` to respond to the channel the message was sent from.

Comment: , Got error : NameError: name 'user' is not defined

Comment: Again, `user` is not defined within the scope of the function, so you will want to use `message.author.mention`. Also, `user.id` is not defined and as such you will need to use `message.author.id`.

Comment: Oki the last one : NameError: name 'lvl_end' is not defined , i tired : message.author.lvl_end

Comment: For `lvl_end` it seems as though you define it as `int(users[user.id]["experience"] ** (1/4))` so you should be able to use it as `int(users[message.author.id]["experience"] ** (1/4))`.

Comment: Also, you'll need to move the `with` block above the `if` block for that to work as `users` is not yet defined.

Comment: sorry from being annoyed. i tried several times, but its still the same , i updated the post for last things i tested as you steps.