# Discord.py - Storing player warns

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've created a warn command but I want to create a command where a player can check their own or someone else's warns, I don't mind what I have to use (json, logging ect)

The warn command is kinda long so I have only shown the imports & the command itself:

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions
from discord.utils import get

@client.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def warn(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason=None):
 arg=reason
 author=ctx.author
 guild=ctx.message.guild
 overwritee = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
 overwrite = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
 channel = get(guild.text_channels, name='warn-logs')
 mrole = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Multi-Galaxy")

 if channel is None:
  channel = await guild.create_text_channel('warn-logs', category=category)
  overwritee.read_messages = False
  overwritee.read_message_history = False
  overwritee.send_messages = False
  overwrite.read_messages = True
  overwrite.read_message_history = True
  overwrite.send_messages = True
  await channel.set_permissions(guild.default_role, overwrite=overwritee)
  await channel.set_permissions(mrole, overwrite=overwrite)

 if member is None:
  await ctx.send("Please specify a user and/or reason!")

 await channel.send(f'{member.mention} got warned for: ```\n{arg}\n``` Warned by: {author.mention}')
 await member.send(f'You got warned for: ```\n{arg}\n``` Warned by: {author} Warned on: **{guild.name}**')
 await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} got warned for: ```\n{arg}\n``` Warned by: {author.mention}')
 await ctx.message.delete()
````

Comment: Save it to a json file so you don't lose the info when the bot restarts. Then just load the json file into memory when the bot starts, whenever a `warn` happens update the json file. (You could use a txt file as well).

Comment: I can't just update it myself & they wouldn't be able to check warns if I did it that way, the bot is gonna be for someone else & I won't be in their server when it's done, I need it to log so if someone does ```?warns``` it'll show their warns

Comment: ?, the bot needs to save a file tracking the warns for all users. When a user does the command the bot can use that users name as the key to look up how many warns that player has.

Comment: ok well how would I do that? I don't know how to do json

Comment: @DrJakaboii See my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51931901/6779307

Comment: oof ok, might be asking too much here, but could you rewrite that for warns, I don't think I'd be able to do that, I'm not amazing but I'm not the worse, one thing I can't do is that though, if you know what I mean